# Where can I find documentation for TypeScript's built-in types and standard library?

Tags: typescript

I love working with TypesScript (as a former C# dev) and I spend hours every month browsing through the online [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html).

However, I can't seem to find documentation about built-in types such as `Map<T1,T2>`, etc.

The documentation refers to the *standard library* in a few places, but I also cannot seem to find documentation for that (for example, the `Partial<T>` awesome class.

Am I just missing it?

Comment: Is this insufficient? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: yes. That's not an API documentation. That's a handbook, a guide, etc. For the past 15 years, I have been used to documentation about classes like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: @EricLiprandi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects describes native JavaScript things (which are available in TypeScript too). I am not sure whether TypeScript actually defines any own types (probably, it does)

Comment: AFAIK it's not documented, but you can take a look to the source:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/616e6e6ca3e87313cc111413ad74d0b49a6cf667/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1331-L1394

Answer (score 4):

This is not a TypeScript standard library, it's ECMAScript, so you won't find a TS-specific reference.

Luckily there are lots of references for that around. I normally tend to just do a quick Google search and end up in places like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects), which IMO the best place for modern JS reference. If you like Microsoft and MSDN stuff, they have [their own JS-specific reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/javascript-reference), but I don't think it's as good as MDN.

The problem with the above is that it doesn't really refer to how types are treated by TS. You'll find a reference to `Map()`, not to `Map<T1, T2>()`. So which type to use where, especially where generics come into play, is a bit implied.

I found that to quickly check how those types are treated, inspecting a type (e.g. hitting F12 when your cursor is over a type in Visual Studio Code) suffices. It'll take you to the specific (internal) definition of the type. For example, for `Map`, you'll be taken to [this piece of code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4604). All the definition libs are also [available online](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib) if you need to check them beforehand.

Comment: Pressing [F12] just brings me to the *.d.ts files; which simply show the same information has the IDE's Intellisense. Actual behavior will not be found in them. As an example (and why I ended up here) I'm looking for documentation for `Map<K,V>`, specifically the behavior of its `delete(k:K)` method and what happens if the key does not exist. That information is not readily found on the TypeScript documentation site - or anywhere else...

Comment: @Zarepheth As described, F12 takes you to the _definition_, not to the _implementation_. Nothing will; it's browser-specific native code, not JavaScript code (and much less TypeScript). In your case, if a key does not exist in `delete(k)` it simply returns `false`. That's described [in the documentation I linked to above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/delete) so I'm not sure what else is needed.